# Remove Dot from String

Tags: c#, string, replace

Trying to remove a Dot from a String i´m experiencing a problem. With different Chars such as "," or "-" its working properly but the Dot won´t disappear.

Got a TextBox with the Name nr_tb. I Input Hello.World and my MessageBox outputs the same. Changing the Dot in the Replace function with a "," works.

Not working:

```
string line; 
private void nr_tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {

            line = nr_tb.Text.Replace(".","");
            MessageBox.Show(line);
    }
```

Working:

```
string line;
private void nr_tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            line = nr_tb.Text.Replace(",","");
            MessageBox.Show(line);
    }
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Eefvu). Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which we can run

Comment: Is it possible that what you think is a dot (decimal point), is actually a different Unicode character (like U11037)?

Comment: Just guessing dot might not be ascii dot :)

Comment: Have a look at *dump*, i.e. `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", inputstring.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4"))));` which codes do you have?

Comment: please post a screen shot from the debugger showing both values for `nr_tb.Text` and `line`

Comment: I get 002e as Output

Comment: can you update your question with a sample input, current output and expected output

Comment: "I get 002e" so, `inputstring` produces `0048 0065 006c 006c 006f 002e 0057 006f 0072 006c 0064` dump and you have common dot `.`?

Comment: is it a real DOT?! it might be another character! like these: `.·¸˙˳̟`

Comment: Also check the dot in your code between quotes and make sure it is common one not a special char.

Comment: So if I wanted to remove a common Dot how would I do that? I´m choosing the Dot in the Code by pressing the Dot on my Keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string number= "2.36"; 
string newNumber = number.Replace(".", "");
```

Comment: No, still getting the Dot.

Comment: Putting it outside the TextChanged works. Any ideas?

Comment: @TeamCrunk i'm Sorry ,i wasn't Active

Answer (score 0):

It might be another character that seems like a DOT. Char code of DOT is `46` so if you get this char code in your string you can easily `Replace(".", "");` it.

This method show each char code of a string:

```
    private static string DotRemover(string temp)
    {
        string _Result = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte a in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp.ToCharArray()))
        {
            _Result += a.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return _Result;
    }
```

OR

you can replace everything that look likes a DOT :

```
public static string CleanNumb(string numb) 
{
    foreach (char c in ".,'´")
       numb = numb.Replace(c, ' ');

    return numb.Replace(" ", "");
}
```